# Why does adding the Images library fail in Julia?

Tags: inno-setup, julia

I'm getting started with Julia 0.3.10 under Windows 7. The language installs and runs, but I can't install the Images package. When I type:

```
Pkg.add("Images")
```

I get output that looks OK, but then the lines below. It looks as if Inno Setup has detected a version problem, but I'm not sure whose version is problematic. 
  I've tried deleting everything "julia" and re-downloading, to no avail. Also, I've searched the web for various pieces of this error message, also stackoverflow; nothing appears to be relevant.

After `Pkg.add("Images")`, a few dozen normal-looking lines, then:

```
INFO: Building Images
INFO: Installing ImageMagick library
INFO: Attempting to Create directory C:\Users\Jim\.julia\v0.3\Images\deps\downloads
INFO: Attempting to Create directory C:\Users\Jim\.julia\v0.3\Images\deps\usr\lib\x64
INFO: Attempting to Create directory C:\Users\Jim\.julia\v0.3\Images\deps\downloads
INFO: Directory C:\Users\Jim\.julia\v0.3\Images\deps\downloads already created
INFO: Downloading file [link at imagemagick] download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.1-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe
INFO: Done downloading file [...]ImageMagick-6.9.1-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe
INFO: Attempting to Create directory C:\Users\Jim\.julia\v0.3\Images\deps\downloads
INFO: Directory C:\Users\Jim\.julia\v0.3\Images\deps\downloads already created
INFO: Downloading file [link at julialang.s3.amazonaws.com]/bin/winnt/extras/innounp.exe
INFO: Done downloading file [link at julialang.s3.amazonaws.com]/bin/winnt/extras/innounp.exe
INFO: Changing Directory to C:\Users\Jim\.julia\v0.3\Images\deps\downloads
```

Here's where I see the first sign of trouble:

```
Signature detected: Inno Setup Setup Data (5.5.6) (u)
This is not directly supported, but i'll try to unpack it as version 5500; Version detected: 5506 (Unicode)
Critical error: The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the program.

Unpacking failed. This version is not supported.

===============================[ ERROR: Images ]================================
```

Comment: This log shows that the Images library (installer ?) uses [`Inno Setup Unpacker`](http://innounp.sourceforge.net/) (which is insane by itself) which does not yet support Inno Setup 5.5.6 at this time. It seems that it uses it to extract some file(s) from the downloaded ImageMagick setup (which seems to be built by Inno Setup 5.5.6). I cannot tell you what to do though. You would need to somehow tell that plugin (installer ?) to download an older version of ImageMagick packed by Inno Setup older than 5.5.6 to get the Inno Setup Unpacker to work.

Comment: But the way that plugin installs itself is crazy. Why does one unpack (crack) a setup archive to get some file(s) instead of downloading the ImageMagick's *.zip archive along with some ZIP archive unpacker and extract the files by that acrhive unpacker I really don't get.

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl/issues if you can.

Comment: @Iain, the dependency deployment is hazardous here. Not just because of this failure, but considering also e.g. the possibility of changing the dependency API (in this case the ImageMagick's library API). It's always better to ship proven versions of dependent stuff from a common source. In this case the author could have download the ImageMagick's ZIP archive (if not directly the needed file, if it does not violate license) with the ZIP archiver from their AWS cloud.

Comment: Yes, so the best way to fix that would be to file an issue... Just like I said.

Comment: `Why does one unpack (crack) a setup archive to get some file(s) instead of downloading the ImageMagick's *.zip archive along with some ZIP archive unpacker and extract the files by that acrhive unpacker I really don't get.`

Why didn't we think of that?!? Oh, wait. They used to only distribute a win32 zip file. That's why. Now that a 64-bit version is available, we will certainly use it.
https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl/issues/68#issuecomment-35051323

Comment: @Isaiah, glad to hear that. Also consider fixing to specific version that you share on your cloud (for the reason I mentioned above). I don't think it's always good to use the latest version (untested with the plugin).

Answer (score 3):

Ah another reason to hate windows. Of course adding this package on Ubuntu had no issues so I switched to my windows installation and low and behold had the same issue as you. The error message as it turns out is quite cryptic but this is how I solved the issue. First I did:

```
    Pkg.update()
```

Then I logged completely out of julia and I went to: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) and downloaded the ImageMagick-6.9.1-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe
making sure to when going through the downloader options to check mark the box that reads:  "Install development headers and libraries for C and C++".

I allowed the installer to install to its default directory and then reopened julia and used the following command:

```
    Pkg.build("Images")
```

Which it successfully did and then I was able to use the images package with the normal command of:

```
   using Images
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Windows. The way of getting the prerequisite is wrong (it uses the setup cracker that supports older version of the installer than the downloaded setup uses).

Comment: @TLama Have you tried it? I did these exact steps and they worked, and I had the exact same issue as James Phillips and it must have something to do with windows if downloading the executable works.

Comment: I've read what the log in the question says. The Inno Setup Unpacker supports Inno Setup packages up to version 5.5.5, whilst ImageMagick is now built by Inno Setup 5.5.6. That's all. But that has nothing to do with Windows at all.

Comment: @TLama Ok fair enough, however I have had many more issues on windows than on Linux that required simple but hard to find fixes in Julia, Python and Matlab.

Comment: @TLama the question I have is why did it work in Ubuntu but NOT in Windows? Because they have to use an unpacker for Windows packages which then creates these types of issues, which does in a sense make it a windows issue.